# Adding current date to a method in YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: java, intellij-14, date

I would like to pass the current date into this method. Eventually I will have a button that I click and it will "Sell an animal"

```
public static void sellingAnimals(int animalschoosen) {
   pets.get(animalschoosen).setSellingDate();
}
```

In my head I think I may need to create a function and call that function in `setSellingDate()` brackets. How would I do this function? or is there a way of passing the current date in this method without a function?

Comment: You have a method `setSellingDate`, what does it do if it does not set the date? Or are you asking how to implement this method?

Comment: What you need is `pets.get(animalschoosen).setSellingDate(LocalDate.now(yourTimeZone));`.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. You can assume that any basic question such as ["getting today's date"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+current+date) has already been addressed in the [1.4 *million* questions/answers on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the current date in the method `setSellingDate()` without using any function.

use `new Date()` and 
to set it to `currentDate`. you can use the following snippet,

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
String currentDateString = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(new Date())
```

Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date()

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.